# SQL get values in multiple rows with same identifiers

Tags: sql

For example, this is my response of

```
select *
from x
where id = 1
```

Result:

```
ID    data  
1     mouse 
1     england
1     computer
```

Now, how do I search for a mouse, in the country England? I can't really check with this:

```
AND data = 'mouse' 
AND data = 'england'
```

(Rather not use a query in a query if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a "set-within-sets" query.  You want to find all three attributes for a given `id`.  I recommend using `group by` and `having` for this purpose:

```
select id
from x
where data in ('mouse', 'england')
group by id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery to constrain the country. For example for this data

```
         ID DATA   
 ---------- --------
          1 computer 
          1 england  
          1 mouse    
          2 austria  
          2 computer 
          2 mouse
          3 mouse 
          3 mouse
```

you first filters only IDs that belongs to England and than 
constrains the Mouse.

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id FROM test WHERE data = 'england'
  )
AND data = 'mouse'; 


         ID DATA   
 ---------- -------- 
          1 mouse
```